# Reporting System Architecture

Tags: .net, sql-server, reporting-services

We have built enterprise/LOB software that, for example, manages orders, customers, inventory, etc. in .NET 3.5 and SQL Server 2008.

We do all kinds of reporting such as

1. traditional reports (SQL queries)
2. dashboards (with charts, lists, etc.)
3. alerts (e.g. if an order is cancelled, email a supervisor)

Right now, we are querying our operations database directly. We are at times having performance problems, and I wonder if this could be solved by either optimizing the way we query the database or something more involved such as using SQL Report Server or replicating the DB on another server and querying against that.

Could you guys lend any suggestions? Or any resources I can read?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

First of all using Reporting Services won't help you much, because you'll end up executing the same queries against the same database, only the rendering engine will change, it can be of some help via [caching](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155927.aspx) the reports though. Whether that will solve your problem depends on your load and where your problem is (inefficient queries will still be slow.)

Optimizing the queries is the first I would attempt, as it never hurts and can only be a good exercise.

If that is not enough I would consider either a read only database replica for reporting, or building an OLAP cube if your reporting can benefit from the data warehouse approach. For this last to work you have to have Analysis Services installed.

Comment: Thank you, Vinko, for the info. Could you please comment on read-only replica vs. OLAP cube? What are the benefits and detriments of each approach? Under which situation would you use each approach?

Comment: A read only replica is useful for transactional reports, where the data is continually changing and need no transformation to be useful (this is, it is useful as is). OLAP, on the other hand, is useful to get different views (transformations) of the data and where the transactional data has to be massaged a lot in code (or SQL) to be useful, or where you need to add more dimensions to the data used (time is the canonical example.)  Read up more on OLAP here:http://wikipedia.org/wiki/OLAP

Answer (score 0):

SSRS can actually help because it has built-in support to cache results and reports. See [Report Caching in Reporting Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155927.aspx).

Comment: Good point. Although that doesn't mean the queries shouldn't be optimized.